# Drools looks up Java classes in camelCase, raises NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, jboss, drools

I've been running a software with a Drools rule engine (version 6.5.0.Final) and it has been running smoothly until recently. I've had to update my version of Eclipse (from Kelper to 2018-09) and somehow the engine doesn't load classes properly anymore. I use Java for object modeling so the class files are in PascalCase; however the Drools module class loader now looks up object types in camelCase, which raises a NoClassDefError leading to engine failure.

The engine runs on a JBoss 6.4 server, and I've been running the program with a jre 1.7. The only difference in configuration is Eclipse's own jdk which is now 1.8, but I fail to see how that would affect the JBoss or Drools engine. I'm not allowed to change JBoss versions so I've only tried to change the JBoss jre but to no avail.

For example :

`not PensionRegimeLiquide( regimeLiquide == $regimeLiquideFuture, droitsTranche == $droitsTranchePosterieure )`

droitsTranche is of type DroitsTranche, but the class loader searches for droitsTranche.class which doesn't exist (only DroitsTranche.class does). Does anyone know what's happening ?

Comment: What do your imports and/or object declaration for DroitsTranche look like?

Comment: The classes aren't imported explicitly, they're public and located in the same package from another project :```package fr.si2m.conseilretraite.moteurcalcul.modele;``` (in the rule and in the class files).